# Does SDL Web 8.1 support Oracle 19c [ 12.2.0.3 ]

Tags: sdl-tridion

i can see in the SDL web 8.1 documentation that it supports Oracle Server 12.1.0.2, but or DBA team wants to update the Oracle Server to Oracle 19c [ 12.2.0.3 ], will SDL web 8.1 Support this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer to your question: **No**

Oracle Server 12.1.0.2 (Enterprise Edition) - supported Sites 8.5

Oracle Server 12.2.0.1 (Enterprise Edition) - supported Sites 9.0

Oracle Server 19c (19.3) (Enterprise Edition) - only supported in Sites 9.1

**Note:**
8.1 already out of support, and 8 and 8.1 already dropped from the sdl documentation portal.

Comment: SDL's Documentation Center website still contains documentation for a lot of older releases of Tridion.

On the homepage of the Documentation Center site, you have to scroll down and click "See more products". After this, the dropdown of releases of SDL Tridion Sites now contains olders versions, up to Tridion 2011 (GA).

Comment: Ah - good to know @Ron

Comment: And to confirm formally: 8.x https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-716B049B-063B-40E9-A7AD-74E12B501AD9

Comment: and for 9.x https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v2/GUID-E542A740-2421-40B9-BEF1-68EE44AD598E